# How to encode string in android & decode string on servlet?

Tags: java, android, servlets, base64, encode

I am trying to encode a parameters in android before sending it to the servlet. I used Base64 class of android & i am able to encode.But on servlet there is no anroid.util so i try to decode through **org.apache.axiom.om.util** so is there any comman class for both servlet & android. I am not using jdk 1.8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same class in both places? The results should be the same so long as both base64 classes do the right thing. You may well find that http://iharder.net/base64 works in both places though, as will many others...

Comment: Try with Guava and its BaseEncoding; note: Guava works on Android too.

Comment: it is not that is why i posted the question

Comment: How about commons-codec from apache